# After importing custom linux subsystem from one machine to another I cannot get ubuntu to have non-root user be the default

Tags: bash, ubuntu, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I exported my Ubuntu subsystem for windows 10 from one machine to another. This worked as expected. Now i am trying to make my user the default instead of root. From new distribution when i run following:

```
lsb_release -a
```

I get following:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I have tried following commands:

```
ubuntu config --default-user <username>
ubuntu1804 config --default-user <username>
Ubuntu config --default-user <username>
Ubuntu1804 config --default-user <username>
lxrun /setdefaultuser <username>
lxrun.exe /setdefaultuser <username>
LxRun /setdefaultuser <username>
LxRun.exe /setdefaultuser <username>
```

Each command shows command not found for example:

```
ubuntu1804 not found
```

This should not be this hard. I must just be missing something small?

Comment: Since there is no code/program involve but only `ubuntu` then I suggests to ask in an ubuntu forum or https://unix.stackexchange.com or a windows forum....

Comment: I was wondering that but i have seen a lot of very similar posts as this on this site

Comment: Mine is just a suggestion though, maybe someone can/will answer that here even though this forum is just for programming/coding or you will just get a downvote.